# HTML from a string in a modal box, which can be invoked as a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a string which contains some HTML . I want this to be displayed in a modal box, which is invoked through a Bookmarklet . Can this be Done.

I have written a JS function which gets some HTML mark-up as a string. 
Now I am trying to display this HTML string as a HTML page in a modal box .

For that I think I first need to convert that string into HTML document, which I can do by

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
return parser.parseFromString(printstr, "text/html")
```

printstr is the string which contains HTML.
Up-to here everything is a breeze. this works well in JavaScript console . The document is being created.

Now what I wanted is that, to display this HTML doc in a modal box(which is nothing but like a alert box of JavaScript but probably can display HTML's too), and more precisely I want to do this from a BookMarklet, because I want this model box to appear on top of some page in which I can't directly add the code for putting the modal window.

Can this Be done.? Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an example using jsfiddle ?

Answer (score -1):

answering your question in a simple way

suppose the string you are trying to load into your modal div is called my_string
where my_string equals "

hi there , im html paragraph element

"

just use plain JS

```
document.getElmentById("my_div").innerHtml=my_string;
```

or using jquery

```
 $("#my_div").html(my_string)
```

where my_div is the your modal div.

Comment: The main catch is that I want this to be invoked through a javaScript Bookmarklet how do I manage that.?

Comment: aha got you , this will help you http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/  , then you can add any code you want inside the function.

Comment: I am trying to create a document out of a string and want that document to load in a modal

Comment: so where is the problem ?! would you please be specific

Comment: can we chat somewhere..?

Comment: add more comments , and we can turn this to chat :)

Comment: ur facebook, can i send u a friend request..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42256/discussion-between-prollygeek-and-rahul888)